# Table, computed property and vuex data

Tags: vuejs2, vuex, computed-properties

I'm in need of help with computed properties .. it's hard to explain but I'll try ..

I have a table with filter and pagination that I created.

When I pass the data directly from a request the API works,
but when I have to work with data coming from vuex I'm having trouble ...

Because I do not know when the data will be filled in vuex

And then I use the computed property because the moment the vuex is filled it will capture the data ..

However as the function that fills the data is the same one that is executed when I click on the page I crash the process and the page stops working.

Below is the computed property:

```
list(){

                if (this.url_get == '' && this.$store.state.table.list.length > 0){         
                    this.total_data = this.$store.state.table.list.length
                    this.repos = this.$store.state.table.list   
                    this.getPaginatedItems(1)               
                }

                var filter = this.configs.filter.toString().toLowerCase()

                var items = ''

                if (filter == ''){
                    items = this.dados
                }else{
                    items = this.repos
                }

                const list = this.$lodash.orderBy(items, this.configs.orderBy, this.configs.order)

                this.reverse = 1;

                if (this.$lodash.isEmpty(filter)) {
                    return list;
                }

                var result = this.$lodash.filter(list, repo => {
                    return repo[this.filter_term].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) >= 0
                })

                return result

            },
```

And the function:

```
getPaginatedItems(data) {

                var items = this.repos

                var page = data

                var per_page = 10
                var offset = (page - 1) * per_page
                var max_item = offset+per_page
                var paginatedItems = this.$lodash.slice(items, offset, max_item)

                var obj = {
                    offset: offset,
                    current_page: page,
                    per_page: per_page,
                    total: items.length,
                    total_pages: Math.ceil(items.length / per_page),
                    data: paginatedItems,
                    last: offset+paginatedItems.length,
                    max_item: max_item
                }

                this.pagination = obj

                this.dados = this.pagination.data
            },
```

Request who fill the data in vuex

```
axios
                    .get(`api/getusuariosgrupo/${id}`)
                    .then(res => {

                        if (res.data.dados !== undefined && res.data.dados.length !== 0){

                            vmThis.isEditing = true

                            var d = {
                                list: res.data.dados,
                                length: res.data.dados.length
                            }

                            this.$store.commit('SET_TABLE', d)

                        }else{
                            vmThis.isEditing = false
                        }

                        vmThis.$bus.$emit('processando',{val: false})
                    })
```

Comment: How and where are you calling the function/API call so that the required data will be stored in Vuex?

Comment: I have other componet who uses a table component, and he request data to API and fill the data in vuex.

Comment: this.$store.state.table.list